# Calling $http.get() multiple times always returns cached result

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, jqxhr

I have an angular controller that makes repeated gets via the $http object, like this:

```
$scope.refresh = function() 
{
    let url = 'api/get-status';
    $http.get( url ).then( function( response )
    {
        console.log( response.data );
    });
};

$scope.intervalFunction = function() 
{
    $timeout( function() 
    {
        $scope.refresh();
        $scope.intervalFunction();
    }, 2000 ) // msec
};

$scope.refresh();
$scope.intervalFunction();
```

The fetches appear to happen. When I do this in chrome I see the results coming back as expected in the console - except the result is just a repeat of the same content I get from the first result.

Whats extra inexplicable is I can turn off the server and the code continues to run without errors. When I look in the chrome's network view, chrome claims its continuing to make successful calls to the server.

Its as if the browser itself is returning cached results and lying about the fetches its making.

Comment: What does the server return in the expires and max-age headers?

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. The headers tell the browser to cache the results. What is weird is that chrome network tab still considers these to be valid fetches with 200 status code and everything.

Comment: I get 200's marked as 'from cache' in the size column as well. Have you tried disabling the cache in your network tab?

Comment: I fixed it on the server end. it should not be setting cache headers. YOur insight was right on.